# Bulk insert CSV file

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I have a Java code which creates a CSV file and then I use the SQL Sever "BULK INSERT" to insert the data into database; I have no format file. The SQL server is 2008.

When I run the code thru unit test and then run the following sql code everything works fine and the data gets inserted into table:

```
declare
@csvFileName VARCHAR (1024)= 'file.csv',
@csvFormatFileName VARCHAR (1024)= null,
@tableName VARCHAR (256) = 'tableName';

EXECUTE (       
'BULK INSERT '+ @tableName +' FROM ''' + @csvFileName + ''' WITH 
(FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR=''\t'', ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'', MAXERRORS=0);');
```

When my Java code runs in production and creates the CSV files, if I grab one of the CSV files created, and run the above SQL, it gives me no error, however no data is inserted into table, I just get:

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

I first thought its the production DB server vs. dev DB server that causes the issue, but that was not the case.

This is the sample data in CSV file:

```
ID  Date    number1 number2 number3

88  2013-01-14  2   0   0.00

64  2013-01-14  0   0   0.00
```

I cannot see any difference bet. the CSV file that runs with no problem and the one that does not! After all they are created with the same Java code.

Is there any editor that can show me the contents of the files exactly as they are with tab, new line, ...?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the csv file `FieldTerminator` should be `,`. Why are you using `\t` delimiter for a csv file? You can save that file as a `.txt` and not `.csv` if you are not storing them as comma separated values.

Comment: I use \t b/c that's what separates my fields.

Comment: then do not use `.csv` extension for file use `.txt`, `.csv` is used for comma separated values. All the fields will be considered as one column if they are not separated by  `,` in a `csv` file

Comment: Use Notepad++, then you can click the "Show All Characters" button to see all the new lines, tabs, carriage returns etc in the file

Comment: I saved the file as .txt and ran the SQL, still got the same results: no rows inserted.

Comment: I would recommend checking the obvious stuff, like is the file path you think your loading actually the one it's trying to load, etc. Also, can you get the prod file to load on the dev server?

Comment: @steoleary: Sorry I cannot find the "Show All Characters" in Notepad++, would you please tell me where that is?

Comment: @muhmud: I already did try that.

Comment: @blueSky, click `View > show symbols > show all characters` in notepad++

Comment: Thanks so much, Notepad++ showed me the difference bet. files, the one that works has CR and then LF at the end of each line but the one that does not work, has only LF and no CR. I'm going to find out why and then see if that works. I'm still puzzled thou, b/c its the same Java code that created both files!

Comment: So looks like the line terminators are a function of the operating system so on my dev file I have CRLF and on prod one I only have LF. I tried the sql command with ROWTERMINATOR=''\r\n'', ROWTERMINATOR=''\n\r'' and also ROWTERMINATOR=''\r'' and none worked. Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What versions of SQL Server are your Dev and Prod servers?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 on dev and prod. OS: MS Windows on dev, not sure what server on prod thou, looks like its Linux b/c it add only LF at the end of each line.

Comment: How exactly is the SQL code getting executed on the Prod server?  SSMS?  Stored Procedure?  Or are you executing it from your Java code?  If so, can you show us the actual code that is invoking the SQL code above?

Comment: It might be security.  SQL server might not have access to view files in the directory you load from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ones on my machine created on Windows which adds CRLF at the end of each line. The ones on production created on Uinx which adds only LF.  The solution would be to use format file created by MS SQL Server bcp utility which works on any platform.